# Double to int and double to int

Tags: java, casting, int, double

I want to know what happened when `Double` invert to int on my example?

this case is right

```
Double d = 123.13;
int i = (int)(Math.random()*d);
```

this case is wrong

```
Double d = 123.13;
int i = (int)(d);
```

[image]
error message:`Inconvertible types;cannot cast'java.lang.Double'to'int'`

and I know I can use ***`d.intValue`*** to do this, but I just want to know what is the difference about the two situations above

Comment: Add error Messages as text not as image

Comment: `Double` cannot be cast to `int`: because `int` is not a sub-type of `Double`

Comment: `Math.random()*d` is of type `double`, not `Double`.

Comment: @ernest_k `double` isn't a sub type of `Double` either. It's just that the conversion is defined.

Comment: ```int i = d.intValue()```

Comment: @AndyTurner Right. When there's no special relationship between the two, we check super/sub-type relationships. That's where I came from. *But I know I'm now taking this too far :-)*

Comment: double is `primitive` but Double is `Class` , you know `d.intValue` actual cast `double` to `int`, but be careful not  cast `Double`  to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

A wrapper type can be cast only to the primitive type that it wraps.

i.e. you can cast a `Double` to a `double`, but not directly to an `int`.

The second snippet can pass compilation with:

```
Double d = 123.13;
int i = (int)(double)(d);
```

In the first snippet, you are casting a primitive (the type of `Math.random()*d` is `double`), to an `int`, which is allowed.

Comment: thanks for your answer what is very detailedness!!

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the primitive value like this, too:

```
Double d = 123.13;
int i = (int) d.doubleValue();
```

…which is pretty much the same as the answer given by Eran.

Comment: Yes, or `int i = d.intValue();`.

Comment: nice,thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Situation 1: `Double d = 123.13;int i = (int)(Math.random()*d);`

Situation 2: `Double d = 123.13;int i = (int)(d);`

**What is difference about the two situations above?**

In the first case `Math.random()` returns a `double`, not `Double`, so this one is right because `double` can be cast to int (losing the fraction part).

Situation 2 is wrong and the reason is explained in @Eran's answer, *A wrapper type can be cast only to the primitive type that it wraps.* i.e you cannot cast `Double` to nonconvertible primitive `int`

Comment: understand,thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of thing going on, see [JLS 5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) .

2nd one is wrong because [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) is class and `double` is [primitive data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Narrowing is possible using primitive data type only

[JLS 5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

> 22 specific conversions on primitive types are called the narrowing primitive conversions:
>
> short to byte or char
>
> char to byte or short
>
> int to byte, short, or char
>
> long to byte, short, char, or int
>
> float to byte, short, char, int, or long
>
> **double to byte, short, char, int, long, or float**

So to your code to work you can change your code like below

```
double d = 123.13;
int i = (int)d;
```

Comment: ok,i understand what you want to say,i'll go to see the Boxing Conversion .Thanks for your answer!